# Javascript Data Layer Architecture Assistance

Tags: javascript, html, data-layers

I'm making a fairly complex HTML 5 + Javascript game. The client is going to have to download images and data at different points of the game depending on the area they are at. I'm having a huge problem resolving some issues with the Data Layer portion of the Javascript architecture.

The problems I need to solve with the Data Layer:

1. Data used in the application that becomes outdated needs to be automatically updated whenever calls are made to the server that retrieve fresh data.
2. Data retrieved from the server should be stored locally to reduce any overhead that would come from requesting the same data twice.
3. Any portion of the code that needs access to data should be able to retrieve it easily and in a uniform way regardless of whether the data is available locally already.

What I've tried to do to accomplish this is build a data layer that has two main components:
1. The portion of the layer that gives access to the data (through get* methods)
2. The portion of the layer that stores and synchronizes local data with data from the server.

The workflow is as follows:

When the game needs access to some data it calls get* method in the data layer for that data, passing a callback function.

```
bs.data.getInventory({ teamId: this.refTeam.PartyId, callback: this.inventories.initialize.bind(this.inventories) });
```

The get* method determines whether the data is already available locally. If so it either returns the data directly (if no callback was specified) or calls the callback function passing it the data.

If the data is not available, it stores the callback method locally (setupListener) and makes a call to the communication object passing the originally requested information along.

```
getInventory: function (obj) {

    if ((obj.teamId && !this.teamInventory[obj.teamId]) || obj.refresh) {
        this.setupListener(this.inventoryNotifier, obj);
        bs.com.getInventory({ teamId: obj.teamId });
    }
    else if (typeof (obj.callback) === "function") {
        if (obj.teamId) {
            obj.callback(this.team[obj.teamId].InventoryList);
        }
    }
    else {
        if (obj.teamId) {
            return this.team[obj.teamId].InventoryList;
        }
    }
}
```

The communication object then makes an ajax call to the server and waits for the data to return.

When the data is returned a call is made to the data layer again asking it to publish the retrieved data.

```
getInventory: function (obj) {
    if (obj.teamId) {
        this.doAjaxCall({ orig: obj, url: "/Item/GetTeamEquipment/" + obj.teamId, event: "inventoryRefreshed" });
    }
},
doAjaxCall: function (obj) {

    var that = this;

    if (!this.inprocess[obj.url + obj.data]) {
        this.inprocess[obj.url + obj.data] = true;
        $.ajax({
            type: obj.type || "GET",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            data: obj.data,
            url: obj.url,
            async: true,
            success: function (data) {
                try {
                    ig.fire(bs.com, obj.event, { data: data, orig: obj.orig });
                }
                catch (ex) {
                    // this enables ajaxComplete to fire
                    ig.log(ex.message + '\n' + ex.stack);
                }
                finally {
                    that.inprocess[obj.url + obj.data] = false;
                }
            },
            error: function () { that.inprocess[obj.url + obj.data] = false; }
        });
    }
}
```

The data layer then stores all of the data in a local object and finally calls the original callback function, passing it the requested data.

```
publishInventory: function (data) {

    if (!this.inventory) this.inventory = {};

    for (var i = 0; i < data.data.length; i++) {
        if (this.inventory[data.data[i].Id]) {
            this.preservingUpdate(this.inventory[data.data[i].Id], data.data[i]);
        }
        else {
            this.inventory[data.data[i].Id] = data.data[i];
        }
    }

    // if we pulled this inventory for a team, update the team
    // with the inventory
    if (data.orig.teamId && this.team[data.orig.teamId]) {
        this.teamInventory[data.orig.teamId] = true;
        this.team[data.orig.teamId].InventoryList = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < data.data.length; i++) {
            this.team[data.orig.teamId].InventoryList.push(data.data[i]);
        }
    }

    // set up the data we'll notify with
    var notifyData = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < data.data.length; i++) {
        notifyData.push(this.inventory[data.data[i].Id]);
    }

    ig.fire(this.inventoryNotifier, "refresh", notifyData, null, true);
}
```

There are several problems with this that bother me constantly. I'll list them in order of most annoying :).

1. Anytime I have to add a call that goes through this process it takes too much time to do so. (at least an hour)
2. The amount of jumping and callback passing gets confusing and seems very prone to errors.
3. The hierarchical way in which I am storing the data is incredibly difficult to synchronize and manage. More on that next.

Regarding issue #3 above, if I have objects in the data layer that are being stored that have a structure that looks like this:

```
this.Account = {Battles[{ Teams: [{ TeamId: 392, Characters: [{}] }] }]}
this.Teams[392] = {Characters: [{}]}
```

Because I want to store Teams in a way where I can pass the TeamId to retrieve the data (e.g. `return Teams[392];`) but I also want to store the teams in relation to the Battles in which they exist (`this.Account.Battles[0].Teams[0]`); I have a nightmare of a time keeping each instance of the same team fresh and maintaining the same object identity (so I am not actually storing it twice and so that my data will automatically update wherever it is being used which is objective #1 of the data layer).

It just seems so messy and jumbled.

I really appreciate any help.

Thanks

Comment: Have you considered using [Backbone](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/) or a similar client-side framework? That would take care of a lot of the grunt work for you.

Comment: I looked at backbone before I implemented this code. At the time I decided it wasn't what I needed. Fed up with my current code I looked at backbone again tonight and am still of the impression that it isn't what I need here. For one I wouldn't need to make use of the views or templates (including any data binding that comes with them) but secondly, it doesn't appear to handle any local indexed storage which is really what I'm after.

Comment: You can pick and choose the parts of Backbone that you need, the data and event management parts are very useful even if you don't use the views. I'll just leave this here: https://github.com/jeromegn/Backbone.localStorage

Comment: Fair enough, I think backbone would simplify the routing. I don't see it satisfying the data storage needs though I only know what I've read in the tutorials which presumably don't paint the whole picture.

Comment: Looking at the data storage problem a bit more I thought it might be suitable to use a nosql db if there were a javascript library that provides that type of interface. I didn't see one, but maybe that will get someone else's juice flowing on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

+1 for Backbone -- it does some great heavy lifting for you.

Also look at the Memoizer in Douglas Crockford's book Javascript the Good Parts.  It's dense, but awesome.  I hacked it up to make the `memo` data store optional, and added more things like the ability to set a value without having to query first -- e.g. to handle data freshness.

Comment: this is the closest thing to what I need. I may be able to use memoizer. Haven't had the time to finalize any of my research on it yet, but the bounty was about to expire so I want to award it to the most-deserving answer

Answer (score 2):

You should consider using jquery's deferred objects.

Example:

```
var deferredObject = $.Deferred();
$.ajax({
     ...
     success: function(data){
         deferredObject.resolve(data);
     }
});
return deferredObject;
```

Now with the deferredObject returned, you can attach callbacks to it like this:

```
var inventoryDfd = getInventory();
$.when(inventoryDfd).done(function(){
     // code that needs data to continue
}
```

and you're probably less prone to errors. You can even nest deferred objects, or combine them so that a callback isn't called until multiple server calls are downloaded.

Comment: I looked at the docs for this and read through two blog posts but I don't see how I could use this to better the situation. Do you have a suggestion as to where I would make use of this? I could use it instead providing a success function for the ajax call, but it would work the same essentially.